# How to diagnose Segmentation Fault on Node.Js

Tags: node.js, segmentation-fault, socket.io

My Node.Js application occasionally fails with a "Segmentation fault" and I am at a loss as to how to diagnose the cause.   As mentioned below I have dramatically reduced their frequency by raising maxlisteners but not made the problem go away.

The application runs on a BeagleBone Black under Node v0.8.22 and uses Socket.io to communicate realtime data to browser pages displayed on the BBB's LCD display.  It collects data from a sensor connected via I2C using the korevec/node-i2c library.  I have, however, isolated that library and still have failures.

The failures generally occur when I have streamed data for a while to the client though they will occasionally/rarely happen at other times as well.  This is not surprising as my app uses socket.io to communicate on almost all pages but the streaming page is at much higher volume.

I am getting the below message:

> (node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11
>   listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
>   Trace

and have been doing so since day 1. I was also seeing the symptoms of a memory leak but since I raised the MaxListeners memory usage stays constant.  Failure rate after making this change went down dramatically but has not gone away completely.   I am using socket.io on top of http and raised MaxListeners for both socket.it and for http.

How does one go about diagnosing this problem?   Is the memory leak error related?  I can post code but there is quite a bit of it and I am not sure what parts are most relevant.

Thanks for any help,
Cheers, Will

Comment: Some additional information following further experimentation.   I am grabbing observations from the i2c sensor using an interval.   I want the highest possible observations per second though there is a physical limit of how long an observation takes (ranging from 4-8ms with the average being 5.3).   When I set my interval to 5 I get in the range of 180-190 obs/sec.   When I set it to 6 I get 155-160.  In both cases less than the interval would suggest due to some observations taking longer.   Could this be the cause of an eventual failure?   Failures happen less frequently at interval 6...?